# Optimal way to develop a group of methods

Tags: oop, c#-4.0, apex-code

I have 50+ types of requests each one has parameters to do fees calculations (e.g. request of type X fees is calculated by area * number of previous submissions)
What I have done was a big IF that checks type of request then calls another class that has method to calculate fees for each type.
There must be a cleaner way to do this, any suggestions?

```
if(mySubmittal.Name == Label.STS_zadc_01) 
myTempRequest.Fees__C = myFeeCalculator.LandDemarcationRequestFees(myTempRequest.Number_of_Points__c) ;
else if(mySubmittal.Name == Label.STS_zadc_02)
myTempRequest.Fees__C = myFeeCalculator.RequestForSiteServicesInformation();
```

and so on ... I ended up with a huge ugly class

Comment: do you have some code to share?

Comment: Code goes like 

if(mySubmittal.Name == Label.STS_zadc_01)
   myTempRequest.Fees__C = myFeeCalculator.LandDemarcationRequestFees(myTempRequest.Number_of_Points__c) ;

        else if(mySubmittal.Name == Label.STS_zadc_02)
             myTempRequest.Fees__C = myFeeCalculator.RequestForSiteServicesInformation();

and so on .....

Comment: one way you can avoid "if" is to use switch statement which makes your code a bit cleaner

Comment: Welcome to SO.  That sample code is highly valuable to your question.  I'd suggesting putting it in the main body of your question, which will also allow for better formatting and presentation.  Generally, sample code can contribute greatly to the success of a question.

Comment: Additionally, put it in a well-formatted code block

Comment: Thanks for your welcome and suggestions and sorry for being newbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always avoid big IF or SWITCH, it's very unreadable and hard to maintain. Polymorphism in OOP is a cure for that. As for your problem, *[command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)* may help. A sample code could be:

```
public interface IRequest
{
    void Execute();
}

public class RequestManager
{
    private Dictionary<string, IRequest> requests = new Dictionary<string, IRequest>();

    // register a request by its unique label/name
    public void RegisterRequest(string name, IRequest request)
    {
        requests.Add(name, request);
    }

    // execute a request according to its label/name
    // thanks to polymorphism, no IF/SWITCH any more
    public void ExecuteRequest(String name)
    {
        requests[name].Execute();
    }   
}


public class LandDemarcationRequest : IRequest
{
    private FeeCalculator myFeeCalculator;
    private Request myTempRequest;

    public LandDemarcationRequest(...)
    {
        //initialization ...
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        myTempRequest.Fees__C = 
            myFeeCalculator.LandDemarcationRequestFees(myTempRequest.Number_of_Points__c);
       // more code...
    }
}

public class SiteServicesInformationRequest : IRequest {
    // similar to the above...
}

// more requests...
```

If these requests has some common codes, you can further factor out them into an abstract base class(to be inherited from), or better, into a new concreate class(to be composed of).

By adopting IF/SWITCH way, the only way to add a new type of request is to modify these IF/SWITCH statements, which breaks [Open/Closed Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle). As you can see, this problem has been resolved by introduction of polymorphism. The other benefit of my proposal is that you can register any request in the runtime, while IF/SWITCH statements are fixed in the compile time.